# How set and retrieve value var between JAVA and GLSL?

Tags: java, parameter-passing, glsl

how set and retrieve value var between JAVA code and GLSL code?

● 1 - "file.java" - (here, want to create the var and set it)

```
public class BANANA
{
    // (code)
    // (code)

    public static float ICE;
    ICE = 0.2f;

    // (code)
    // (code)
}
```

● 2 - "fragment.glsl" - (here, i want to retrieve the value)

```
#ifdef GL_ES
    precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform float ICE;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.1, ICE, 0.3, 0.9);
}
```

What is the method to retrieve the var ICE in my "fragment.glsl" file? - Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

NOTE:
Thanks to @Rabbid76, this is the final code that works perfectly for everyone who needs it.

● 1 - "file.java" - (LibGDX with main class: > render())

```
public class BANANA
{
    // (code)
    // (code)

    public static float ICE;
    public static int   ICE_Location;
    //
    ICE                 = 0.0f;
    ICE_Location        = 0;

    // (code)
    // (code)



    // ---------------------------------
    @Override
    public void render()
    {
        // (code)
        // (code)

        batch.begin(); // - give the command into this SCOPE, otherwise it will not work
        //
        ICE_Location = shader.getUniformLocation("ICE"); // - retrieve var's address
        shader.setUniformf(ICE_Location, 1.0f);          // - set var's value by address
        //
        batch.end();

        // (code)
        // (code)
    }
}
```

● 2 - "fragment.glsl"

```
#ifdef GL_ES
    precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform float ICE;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.1, ICE, 0.3, 0.9);
}
```

Tested, work 100%.
Problem solved, i hope it will help others...